# Primes of the form power of 2 plus a prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

By Bertrand' postulate, there exists a prime between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$.

For every $n$, is there a prime $p < 2^n$ such that $2^n+p$ is a prime?

The smallest such primes are listed in OEIS A056206.

Comment: It seems like you’re hoping for an effective form of Dickson’s conjecture.

Comment: @Charles Similar. My question contains a constraint $p < 2^n$. 
The prime $p$ could be large according to the value $n$.

Comment: It's not even known whether every power of two is a difference of two primes, is it?